# Access files and Classes in another project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 2 projects at this hierarchy

```
*Project1
  **src
      ***Class1

*Project2
    **src
      ***Main
```

Can i access ***Class1*** Class that is in Project1 in ***Main*** Class that is in Project2

Is this possible OR not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...you can..

**1.** What you can do is create a jar of the project you're getting the class from via `Export->Java->JAR file` and put that file into your project. This will let you access the class you need while still keeping your projects self-contained.

**2.** Use `import`, and voila....you now have the access.....

**/////////////////////Edited///////////////////////**

Use this to import the project in your current project...

**In eclipse do this...**

`Build Path ---> Configure Path ----> Click Project Tab ---> Add the project.`

But still using `Jar` is much `more easier while importing and exporting`..and you can give the `version numbers` to jar, and can **mention the changes in them...**

Comment: But if i make changes at Project1 . I cant see it ---> because as your answer i will read from exported JAR not from Project1 :(

Comment: I am not an eclipse expert but isn't it possible to reference another project without creating a jar? In IntelliJ it is possible (it's called modules there btw.)

Comment: Ya offcourse.... you are right at this....but usually Jar files are used as its flexible in importing and Exporting... Fine if you want to just use another project in your another project with no intension of sharing it.. `see my edited part...`

Comment: @Kumar Vivek Mitra ---> :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

It is, you would need to link the projects. Right click on

```
Project2 > Properties > Java Build Path > Projects > Add
```

then select your project.

If your project is in a different workspace than use

```
Project2 > Properties > Java Build Path > Folder > Link Source
```

select your folder.

Comment: Then you can still use Source > Link Source and select the folder.